# Creating a 3D plot with Tikzpicture and Gnuplot from a matrix data file

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I wanted to create a 3D plot in LaTeX with Tikzpicture and Gnuplot with a data matrix. So far I got a plot which looks like 
[image: example 3D plot]

My code so far:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid, zmin=0, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$}, zlabel style={rotate=-90}]
        \addplot3[raw gnuplot, surf] gnuplot [surf]{
            splot "Plots/data.dat" matrix with lines;
        };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

How can I change the z-axis so that it looks correct? I tried using

```
xmin=0, xmax=10
ymin=0, ymax=10
```

but then the numbers overlap and it looks pretty ugly. Is there a way to scale the numbers or change their positions so they don't overlap?

Is there a way to change the color mapping or just use a mesh so that it looks more appealing?

The data matrix

```
22134   134044  2009854 1981520 185256  133052  595944  70680   36890   31000
328440  1519980 83105400    2370480 559440  657720  2840880 428400  367500  310800
94248   1590480 2515896 181152  69984   79344   435744  108000  93240   116640
343570  167743  669811  78948   29412   42398   382700  95460   121905  307020
43741   53909   352377  40052   18972   44950   408332  150660  387345  46500
42772   86292   543932  78608   61200   145928  1960848 1456560 178500  55760
197829  384883  3084667 732700  574092  2024838 54776652    1939500 618485  198260
20995   51935   684125  163540  189540  1345890 1735500 159900  52325   18200
7225    29375   389425  137700  321300  108750  364900  34500   12250   7000
9775    39997   784323  558348  62100   54694   188324  19320   11270   7360
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

With this

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid, xmin=0, xmax=9, ymin=0, ymax=9, zmin=0, 
        xtick={2,6}, ytick={1,6}, ztick=\empty,
        xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$}, 
        zlabel style={align=right, rotate=-90}, 
        scaled ticks=false, 
        view={45}{30},
    ]
    \addplot3[raw gnuplot, surf] 
        gnuplot [surf]{
            splot "Plots/data.dat" matrix with lines;
        };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I got to the point where it looks like this
[image: better 3D plot]

The last thing I would like to change is that the first row/column entry in my data matrix are represented by x=1/y=1 and so on instead of x=0/y=0. I couldn't find a solution for this in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf).

Comment: What do you expect?  The picture you see is just what your data looks like ([gnuplot screenshot for comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EwIB.png)).

Comment: Or are you maybe looking for `\begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false,...`?

Comment: scaled ticks=false made it look a bit better. Currently it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/ensowzk.png I don't want both zeros not to be so close to each other/overlap each other. If it is possible, can't I use 1 zero for the x axis and the z axis together?

Comment: Just read [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) on how to setup ticks.

Comment: That's a fantastic manual. With the help of the manual I was able to make the plot look like this: https://i.imgur.com/a2tE8nM.png This is not exactly what I initially wanted but I like this style. There is just one thing left which I would like to change. How can I set x=0 to x=1, y=0 to y=1 and so on. So that the first column/row in my data matrix is a represented by x=1 and y=1 instead of x=0 and y=0? I couldn't find a solution for that in the manual.